# observedAttributes() is not a function

Tags: web-component, custom-element

I have attributes in a [JS Custom Element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element)

```
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['state','color'];
  }
```

How can I get that **whole** array in the `Callback` functions of a Custom Element?

`this.observedAttributes()` is not a function

I must be overlooking something easy...

### Update after question in comment:

I kept forgetting Getter and Setters

I can now do this in the constructor():

```
    this.constructor.observedAttributes.map(attribute => 
    Object.defineProperty(this, attribute, {
      get() {
        return obj.getAttribute(attribute);
      },
      set(newValue) {
        obj.setAttribute(attribute, newValue);
      },
      enumerable: true,//default:false
      configurable: true // default:false
      //writable: true // not valid, since there is a set method!
    }));
```

(don't care about the memory consumption side effects)

Comment: I am currious why you need the whole array. Do you have some cool code that you can share?

Comment: see above, any other side effects besides memory with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`observedAttributes` is defined as `static` so it'll be called off of the class, not an instance. `observedAttributes` is also a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (`get`) so you will not execute it with `()`. If you defined the custom element class as `FancyButton` you should use `FancyButton.observedAttributes`.

Comment: or `this.constructor.observedAttributes`

Comment: cool, ``this.constructor`` works for my as my element class is an anonymous function

Comment: It should be noted that it is not because it is a getter that you do not use `()`,  but because it returns an `Array`. getters that return functions may still use `()`. Clarifying this will help future readers.

Comment: No, `FancyButton.observedAttributes` is a property bound to the `observedAttributes` function defined in the class. You call it without `()`. **If** the response was a function instead of an array, you **could** execute the function by adding a `()`.

Comment: does it have to be static?  My constructor in a derived class defines the attributes I want to observe, but this isn't accessible from a static constructor.  In fact, I'm not even sure when `observedAttributes` is called if it's possible for it to be after the instance is constructed.